# How can i return deleted treeitems in javafx treeview?

Tags: javafx, treeview

How can i returned removed treeitems in Javafx treeview?

When i make a tree like this.

```
root-
    |-item1
    |-item2
    |-folder1-
             |-item3
             |-item4
             |-item5
             |-folder2-....
             |-folder3-....
```

if i delete folder1 i want to get some list of removed items and fodlers, it means that if i remove folder1 i want to get list of item3, item4, item5, folder2, folder3 and more items which was located in folder2 and folder3.

I used remove() function to delete treeitem like this.

```
folder1.getParent().getChildren.remove(folder1);
```

In this case what will be the best way to get removed nodes list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `EventHandler` to your root `TreeItem` to handle [`TreeModificationEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent.html)s. Specifically, you should listen for events with the [`TreeItem#childrenModificationEvent()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#childrenModificationEvent()) event type.

> An EventType used when the TreeItem receives a direct modification to its children list.

```
TreeItem<T> root = ...;
root.addEventHandler(TreeItem.<T>childrenModificationEvent(), event -> {
    if (event.wasRemoved()) {
        List<? extends TreeItem<T>> removed = event.getRemovedChildren();
        // Handle removed children. Traverse descendants as needed.
    }
});
```

*Where `T` is your value type.*

Comment: This is  actually what i want. Thank you :)